# Change Millions and Billions to integers in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro below that takes my Sales column and changes the numbers in the column from Millions or Billions to an integer.  For example, it changes 365M to 365,000,000. I'm trying to alter the code so I can do this with 2 columns instead of just 1.  Nothing I've tried has worked. Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks

```
Sub Sales()
   Dim myCell As Range
   Dim found As Range, myRange As Range
   Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long
   
   With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      .AutoFilterMode = False
      
      Set found = .Cells.Find("Sales", LookIn:=xlValues)
      If Not found Is Nothing Then
         lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
         Set myRange = .Range(found.Offset(1), .Cells(lastRow, found.Column))
   
         'Replace Estimated
         myRange.Replace What:="(Estimated);", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
            
         For Each myCell In myRange
            If Trim(myCell) <> "" Then
               myCell = Replace(myCell, Chr(160), "")
               myCell = Replace(myCell, "$", "")
               myCell = Replace(myCell, ".", ",")
               If Right(myCell, 1) = "K" Then
                  myCell = Int(Left(myCell, Len(myCell) - 1)) * 1000
               ElseIf Right(myCell, 1) = "M" Then
                  myCell = Int(Left(myCell, Len(myCell) - 1)) * 1000 ^ 2
               ElseIf Right(myCell, 1) = "B" Then
                  myCell = Int(Left(myCell, Len(myCell) - 1)) * 1000 ^ 3
               End If
            Else
               myCell = 0
            End If
         Next
      Else
         MsgBox ("Revenue1 not found")
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have adjacent neighbour columns, e.g. this and the next one, it suffices to extend the initial range setting by `.Resize(, 2)` to enclose not only one, but two columns for example. - Btw if changing greater ranges I'd prefer to assign values to an array first, change values therin and write the changed array values back eventually.

Comment: This worked for me very well.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all the element in a multi-dimensional range, I believe you should use the following

```
For Each myCell In myRange.Areas
```